# got my schengen visa from finland

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, multiple-entry

I will get my visa from the finish consulate in St. Petersburg by Monday. I don't know if its multiple or single entry. I asked them in the interview that I need it to be a multiple entry visa. I also informed them that I am going to stay around 4 days in Finland and I will take a round trip through Europe.

My question is would there be any problem if I just enter Finland and on the same day I take the plane to Germany and stay there till my visa is valid?

And if I can travel from Germany direct back to St.Peter would there be any problem or would I have to go back to Finland?

Answer (score 7):

- When you *already have* a Schengen visa, you can make minor changes to your itinerary as long as the overall premise of the trip remains unchanged.
- When you *apply for* a Schengen visa, you are not allowed to lie about your itinerary.

In the situation you describe, you could be suspected of lying to get a visa from Finland and not from Germany.

Answer (score 2):

They will ask you for your itinerary when you land. If you tell them the truth, they may refuse entry and ban you for breaching the "main destination rule." If you lie and they find out, they will refuse entry and ban you.

http://m.saudiarabien.diplo.de/contentblob/3179408/Daten/1327578/Schengen_regulations.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjgv93grrXXAhXDu48KHe-ZCRAQFggdMAE&usg=AOvVaw0zXvLUT57odjztXh4L0kyw

However, many people do what you plan to do without getting caught. You need to decide whether or not it's worth the risk.

Comment: I already inform them that i am going to stay for few days and going to round and I will make hotel booking in Finland after I get in Finland in the airport there is no immigration to ask you whether in Finland nor in Germany

Comment: I just had last minuit change in the itinerary

Comment: If your change is so significant so that you're not really visiting Finland, that's a potential problem. You told them you were visiting Finland, and now you're going to take an entirely different trip. If you are questioned, they will suspect you have lied to them because you applied for one trip and are now doing something completely different. You could be denied entry or denied future Schengen visas.